# Table row does not get delete at all

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I need to delete all the table content except the head and the initial row where the user can input items. I run a loop over the table length which delete every row that is not with the id of the two rows that I want to except. There is a row that should not match the exception in the if statement but **NEVER** get deleted. What is the problem?

Here is the HTML (please not the `<script src="myscript.js"></script>` that you may need to edit):

```
<HTML>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<table align='center' cellspacing=2 cellpadding=5 id="data_table" border=1>

<tbody><tr id="head">
<th>Name</th>
<th>Type</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>

<tr id="row-1">
<td id="col-1">AAAA</td><td id="col-2">A</td>
<td id="col-3">
    <button type="button" class="edit-button" id="edit-button-1">Edit</button>
    <button type="button" class="save-button" id="save-button-1">Save</button>
    <button type="button" class="delete-button" id="delete-button-1">Delete</button>
</td>
</tr>

<tr id="row-3"><td id="col-1">BBB</td>
<td id="col-2">B</td><td id="col-3">
    <button type="button" class="edit-button" id="edit-button-3">Edit</button>
    <button type="button" class="save-button" id="save-button-3">Save</button>
    <button type="button" class="delete-button" id="delete-button-3">Delete</button>
</td>
</tr>

<tr id="initial-row">
<td><input id="text-field" type="text"></td>

<td>
    <select name="levels-list" id="levels-list">
    <option value="A" id="option-1">A</option>
    <option value="B" id="option-2">B</option>
    <option value="C" id="option-3">C</option>
    </select>
</td>

<td><input class="add" id="add-button" value="Add" type="button"></td>
</tr>
<script src="myscript.js"></script>
</tbody>

</table>
</div>
</HTML>
```

Here is the script:

```
var table = document.getElementById("data_table");
for(var y=0; y<table.rows.length; y++)
  {
    console.log("deleting row "+ y);

    if ((table.rows[y].id!= "initial-row") && (table.rows[y].id!= "head"))
    {
      console.log("inside if statement");
      table.deleteRow(y); //delete the row
      console.log("row deleted");
    }
    else{ console.log("inside else. row is not deleted.");}

  }//end for

 console.log(table.innerHTML);
```

**EDIT:**
To clarify, what I actually do is that the table was containing rows assigned ids consequently (row-1, row-2, row-2, row-3). The table is built based on items read from an array. There is a delete button. If an item is deleted, I delete it using `table.deleteRow(rowindex);` and delete the values of that row from an array. The table row ids become non sequent after the deletion. Therefore, I want to delete all the rows except the initial ones (the head and the  initial input) and recompute the ids and build the new table with new ids after the deleted items. The table rows becomes in sequence order without gaps. This is important for me.

Comment: I suppose the problem is that when you are deletting rows, you actually change the number of all following rows. Assume there are four rows in your table and you delete the second one (y = 2), the third one becomes the second and the fourth one becomes the third. Then y becomes 3, and you delete the new third row, which was the fourth before. So the new second/old third row will never be deleted... You should consider using a while loop instead and only increment y when you havent deleted a row.

Comment: @Johannes Lemonde thanks. But your solution did not help. It introduced an error saying `table.rows[y] is undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue is that the indexing changes as you remove rows. If you remove one in a for() loop you need to also change `y`. Or , work in reverse so as you remove rows from bottom the indexing doesn't change.

A cleaner approach is move your head row to a `<thead>` and use `querySelectorAll()` to select the rows you want to remove inside the tbody and use `not()` to exclude the initial row

```js
var table = document.getElementById("data_table");
var rowstoDelete = table.querySelectorAll('tbody tr:not(#initial-row)');

[].slice.call(rowstoDelete).forEach(function(row) {
  row.remove()
});
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <table align='center' cellspacing=2 cellpadding=5 id="data_table" border=1>
    <thead>
      <tr id="head">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="row-1">
        <td id="col-1">AAAA</td>
        <td id="col-2">A</td>
        <td id="col-3">
          <button type="button" class="edit-button" id="edit-button-1">Edit</button>
          <button type="button" class="save-button" id="save-button-1">Save</button>
          <button type="button" class="delete-button" id="delete-button-1">Delete</button>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr id="row-3">
        <td id="col-1">BBB</td>
        <td id="col-2">B</td>
        <td id="col-3">
          <button type="button" class="edit-button" id="edit-button-3">Edit</button>
          <button type="button" class="save-button" id="save-button-3">Save</button>
          <button type="button" class="delete-button" id="delete-button-3">Delete</button>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr id="initial-row">
        <td>
          <input id="text-field" type="text">
        </td>

        <td>
          <select name="levels-list" id="levels-list">
            <option value="A" id="option-1">A</option>
            <option value="B" id="option-2">B</option>
            <option value="C" id="option-3">C</option>
          </select>
        </td>

        <td>
          <input class="add" id="add-button" value="Add" type="button">
        </td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>

  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Given that you've used an appropriate `<thead>` element for the heading elements, the rows that should not be deleted, wouldn't it be easier to simply replace the existing `<tbody>` with a fresh, or otherwise empty, `<tbody>` element as an alternate approach? (I considered posting an answer but, frankly, once the OP understands the reason for the problem the answer is already written, despite the possibility of more solutions.) **Edit** my bad, I didn't see the `#initial-row` element elsewhere. Although that could still be added to a `<tfoot>` element, leaving the same solution...

Comment: @DavidThomas yeah... give main tbody an id even and simply empty it, hadn't thought of that. I think OP will benefit from learning other approaches to selecting elements from answer though also

Comment: @charlietfl but this removes the table head when I run it after I add some data and click delete. How can you make `tbody tr:not(#initial-row)` except tr with id "head"?

Comment: @charlietfl When I tried to add `||` I got: `DOMException [SyntaxError: "'tbody tr:not(#initial-row ||#head)` is not a valid selector".

Comment: @charlietfl I'm using firefox. When I test it in FF, the row with `id=head` gets deleted. How to except it as well?

Comment: you didn't move the head row to a `<thead>`. My demo works fine in firefox

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really into modifying the DOM like this and I can imagine that not all browsers support this way of removing a row. 
I would really suggest to give all rows that you want to delete a extra class so it would be really easy to remove them when using jQuery

```
$('#table-selector-by-id').find ('.to-be-deleted').remove ();
```

Comment: There is no jQuery method `select()`. Also you shouldn't answer questions that aren't tagged jQuery with jQuery code

Comment: Fair enough. Discard my answer.